# Read all data from all databases in my server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I'm working with sql server 2000, and I need to read all data  from all databases
  in my server, because then I will work with some data, how can I make this query? 
  I've tried this code, but doesn't works as I want.

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE TMP_INGRESO_MASIVO_DAT_CLIENTES AS

declare @Fila as int
declare @Script_Dinamico as varchar(8000)
declare @Script_Dinamico1 as varchar(8000)
declare @Nro_Registros as int

Select Distinct  cod_empresa,Nombre_Base Into #Tmp_Bases1 From Estadistica_Cobranza.Dbo.Sis_Conexion_pagos Where Cod_Estado = 1 and Proc_Automaticos= 1--capturo nombre BD
Select Distinct  Identity(Int,1,1) As Fila, cod_empresa , Nombre_Base As Name  Into #Tmp_Bases From #Tmp_Bases1

    Drop table #Tmp_Bases1
    Select @Fila = 1
    Select @Script_Dinamico = ''
    Select @Script_Dinamico1 = ''
    Select @Nro_Registros  =  (Select Count (*) From  #Tmp_Bases ) + 1--cantidad de filas  +1





    While @Fila < = @Nro_Registros 
Begin
    Print(@Script_Dinamico)

Select @Script_Dinamico = 'INSERT INTO buc.dbo.tmp_DAT_CLIENTES '
Select @Script_Dinamico = @Script_Dinamico +'(COD_EMPRESA,'
Select @Script_Dinamico = @Script_Dinamico +'COD_SUCURSALEMPRESA,'
Select @Script_Dinamico = @Script_Dinamico +'RUT_CLIENTE,'
Select @Script_Dinamico = @Script_Dinamico +'RAZON_SOCIAL, '
Select @Script_Dinamico = @Script_Dinamico +'FECHA_CARGA,'
Select @Script_Dinamico = @Script_Dinamico +'FECHA_MODIFICACION'
Select @Script_Dinamico = @Script_Dinamico +')'
Select @Script_Dinamico = @Script_Dinamico +'Select '
Select @Script_Dinamico = @Script_Dinamico +'COD_EMPRESA, '
Select @Script_Dinamico = @Script_Dinamico +'COD_SUCURSALEMPRESA, '
Select @Script_Dinamico = @Script_Dinamico +'RUT_CLIENTE, '
Select @Script_Dinamico = @Script_Dinamico +'RAZON_SOCIAL, '
Select @Script_Dinamico = @Script_Dinamico +'FECHA_CARGA, '
Select @Script_Dinamico = @Script_Dinamico +'FECHA_MODIFICACION'
Select @Script_Dinamico = @Script_Dinamico + ' from ' + (Select Name  From #tmp_bases  Where Fila = @Fila) +'.Dbo.DAT_CLIENTES '
Select @Script_Dinamico = @Script_Dinamico  + 'Where ' + (Select Name  From #tmp_bases  Where Fila = @Fila) +'.Dbo.DAT_CLIENTES.cod_empresa =  '+ convert(varchar,(Select cod_empresa  From #tmp_bases  Where Fila = @Fila))
Select @Script_Dinamico = @Script_Dinamico  +'and '+ (Select Name  From #tmp_bases  Where Fila = @Fila) +'.Dbo.DAT_CLIENTES.rut_cliente not in (select RUT_CLIENTE from tmp_dat_clientes'
Select @Script_Dinamico = @Script_Dinamico+' where '+ (Select Name  From #tmp_bases  Where Fila = @Fila) +'.Dbo.DAT_CLIENTES.rut_cliente = buc.dbo.tmp_DAT_CLIENTES.RUT_CLIENTE )'








            Print ( @Script_Dinamico)
            Exec (@Script_Dinamico )
            Select  @Fila = @Fila +1
            Select @Script_Dinamico = ''
            Select @Script_Dinamico1 = ''



End
Drop Table #Tmp_Bases

GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO
```

Comment: What could you possibly want to do with all of this output? All data from all tables from all databases? Really?

Comment: This also assumes that the tables all have the exact same structure

Comment: yes have all tables the same structure

Comment: @AaronBertrand I need at first all data but then just some data, like id_number, telephone, etc. thanks in advance

Comment: And what do you do with the data that you need first and don't need later?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have the same table (`DAT_CLIENTES`) in many databases, and want to get all of these records if the database name is listed in `Estadistica_Cobranza.Dbo.Sis_Conexion_pagos.Nombre_Base`.

While there are certainly many ways to do this, you seem to have put one together using a while-loop, temp tables and dynamic SQL (all can often have performance and maintenance implications).  However, coding methods and style aside, I'm most concerned with this line:

```
Select @Script_Dinamico = @Script_Dinamico+' where '+ (Select Name  From #tmp_bases  Where Fila = @Fila) +'.Dbo.DAT_CLIENTES.rut_cliente = buc.dbo.tmp_DAT_CLIENTES.RUT_CLIENTE )'
```

The `=` in the dynamic where clause will end up trying to compare the values of a column in one DB each with another entire column in another DB.  Perhaps this should be an `in` or some other operator that can compare a value with a set of values, rather than compare two single values.

Are you getting any error messages?